# Hide and show section using segmented control and fetched results controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I have a segmented control on top of my tableview that includes 3 segments I want to be able to show/hide section(3 section also) based on the selectedIndex of segmented control. I am using core data and nsfetchedresultscontroller for the tableview data.

Answer (score 0):

- Create an IBOutlet for that segmented control and @synthesize it.
- Create an IBAction and use the ValueChanged event
- Inside the method that is wired to that IBAction, just check the state of that segmented control:

  yourSegnmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex

just examine the value and change the predicate for your fetchedResultsController and perform the fetch again.

If you need code for this, I can add it, but this is a fairly straight-forward process.